# How to send an outlook email from generic email address using PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

I am trying to automate sending email task using PowerShell script.

I want to send an email using generic (common) email address, not using current logged in user.

I have tried `SentOnBehalfOfName` property, but no luck, it is still sent an email from current logged in user.

For an exmaple,

My email address is : abc@outlook.net

Generic (common) email address is : common@outlook.net

Here, I want to send an email from `common@outlook.net` from any computer.

Below is my code that I have tried so far.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "common@outlook.net"
$Mail.To = "abc@****.net"
$Mail.Subject = "Test Email"
$Mail.Body = "Testing"
$Mail.Send()
$Outlook.Quit()
```

Please let me know, how can I accomplish it? Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will use native System.Net.SMTPClient:

```
$to = 'mailadress1'
$from = 'mailadress2'
$onBehalfOf = 'mailadress3'
$subject = "powershell send on behalf"
$body = "body"
$smtpserver = "an SMTP server in your domain"
$mailer = new-object Net.Mail.SMTPclient($smtpserver) 
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from,$to,$subject,$body)
$msg.Sender = $onBehalfOf
$mailer.send($msg)
```

Comment: I am working for an organization, and I do not think that they will provide me their SMTPSERVER information to me. So, I am trying to avoid SMTP. Any other way, through I can do it?

Comment: No, for mailing using Exchange or any other mail service through powershell you need the name of The SMTP server

Answer (score 0):

The user account will need to have the `Send on Behalf` permission enabled for that generic account, I've tested this with 2 generic accounts that were setup in my Outlook with the mentioned permission:
[Microsoft - Send email on behalf of another user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/give-mailbox-permissions-to-another-user?view=o365-worldwide#send-email-on-behalf-of-another-user)